# Exact field input mongoose for nodejs

Tags: regex, node.js, mongoose, special-characters, exact-match

I've recently been attempting to pull my hair out getting stuck on what I would call a trivial issue.
The way mongoose in nodejs handles the specific field inputs. I have a specific issue where mongoose is not doing the same as mongodb is doing.

The issue is the following, if I use a "-" symbol in my field name, mongoose seems to run some weird operation on it, instead of accepting it as part of a string.
I've tried running several regex commands, some / escapes, however it should literally just take the input, as I know the specific data I'm looking for.

The code causing the issue is the following:

```
datapoints.find({type: "charging-type", device: device._id})
          .exec(function(err, objects){
                   if(!objects){
                       log("Can't find objects");
                   }
                });
```

Going straight into mongo shell and typing:

```
db.datapoints.count({type: "charging-type", device: device._id})
```

taking out the type makes everything work, changing the type to for example: shuntvoltage, current, ... all work perfectly.

The problem thus occurs with the usage of this - symbol. 
What would be the way to enter this inputstring with a special character as an exact string?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit as per request; I don't get any error, I get objects==undefined (or !objects), schema is below.

```
var datapointSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   type:                { type: String, lowercase: true},
   value:               { type: Number},
   timestamp:           { type: Number},
   device:              { type: ObjectId, ref: "devices"} 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('datapoints', datapointSchema)
```

Comment: I don't think "-" symbol will give any error please update ur answer with schema and error u r getting

Comment: I'm not getting any error, I'm simply not getting any values back. "objects==undefined" (or !objects) is basically true if I run this.

Answer (score 0):

Manually updated the field in mongodb from charging-status to chargingstatus, as no useful answer was produced.

It's a workaround and should be considered unresolved.

Final code ended up looking as such:

```
var cursor = calcpoints.find({device: device._id}).where('type').equals('chargingstatus').sort({timestamp: 1}).cursor();
```